# How i can solve this problem in the Stored Procedure (sql server) c#?

Tags: c#

I am in the project, consist in the abm, so i have a problem with the consult update in the stored procedure

i cant save the stored procedure, but i dont have problems in the views and clases base

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spModificarDestino
/*
(
@parameter1 int = 5,
@parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
)
*/
@id int

AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */

UPDATE Destino
SET DES_Descripcion WHERE DES_Codigo = @id;
```

give me a next error when i click in save.
'Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE'

Comment: you didnt put value of DES_Descripcion, you should put value for set like this: `SET DES_Descripcion = 'test'`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of the update command is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

So your command should be like this...

```
UPDATE Destino
SET DES_Descripcion = 'Val' WHERE DES_Codigo = @id;
```